# Elasticsearch giving query_shard_exception for query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I am storing URL in the elastic search and I making the following request to get a result for elastic  search:

```
{
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png*",
                                "fields": ["url"],
                                "default_operator": "OR"
                            }
                        }
```

but elastic search giving Me the following error:

```
   {
"error": {
    "root_cause": [{
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse query [*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png*]",
        "index_uuid": "-061pFHDRvmeN_-FWT8ZEg",
        "index": "demo"
    }],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [{
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "demo",
        "node": "je7xKjGTTfWn1rKbuVBbhA",
        "reason": {
            "type": "query_shard_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse query [*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png*]",
            "index_uuid": "-061pFHDRvmeN_-FWT8ZEg",
            "index": "demo",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "parse_exception",
                "reason": "Cannot parse '*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png*': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <EOF> \n    <AND> ...\n    <OR> ...\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    ",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "parse_exception",
                    "reason": "Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <EOF> \n    <AND> ...\n    <OR> ...\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    "
                }
            }
        }
    }]
},
"status": 400
```

}

What is the meaning of this error? and How I resolve it?  kindly help me here

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly escape the colon from the query as shown below

```
 "query": "*http\\://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png*"
```

Modify your search query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*http\\://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png*",
      "fields": [
        "url"
      ],
      "default_operator": "OR"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "url.keyword": "http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66830399",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "url": "http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/dt1234/dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a/my.png"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: yes, it works fine but it gave me all results that have the same pattern (like http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/c123/c444/6055555/test.png) is any way in the above query to get only requested URL in the result?

Comment: @SurajDalvi please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Yes both the answers are right and valid but I want to implement contains query here. if someone passes the full URL or some part of the URL like dt3335/605f068b5e124230eadea17a I  want those items that contain this URL.
is an option to get it? Please help me here

Comment: Can I use query like: {
 "query_string": {
  "query": "*http\\:\\/\\/localhost\\:8000\\/v3\\/assets\\/c122\\/d122\\/x122\\/my.png*",
  "fields": ["url"],
  "default_operator": "OR"
 }
}

Comment: can you please help me here?